# Issues with Accord.NET SVM classification task

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

Dearest C#-ers, Accord.NET users and Machine Learning amateurs/professionists,

I am meeting troubles with implementing a Kernel SVM from the Accord.Net Framework.

In particular, my task is to classify (multiple labels) entries of a data set, made of 11 dimensional vector (real valued) plus a categorical integer 12th entry for each one, these ranging from 0 to 10 (despite only 3, ... , 8 are actually present). I am referring to [this](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/red-wine-quality-cortez-et-al-2009) dataset.

I splitted the original dataset (1599 items) in a 10%, kept apart as test set to be used as check once training is performed of the 90% left, indeed as training set.

I followed [this example](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_MulticlassSupportVectorMachine.htm) (bottom, second one).

```
// Let's say we have the following data to be classified
// into three possible classes. Those are the samples:
// 
double[][] inputs =
{
    //               input         output
    new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //  0 
    new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //  0
    new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //  1
    new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, //  1
    new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
    new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
    new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //  1
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 0, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //  2
};

int[] outputs = // those are the class labels
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
};

// Create the multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<Gaussian>()
{
    // Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
    //  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
    Learner = (param) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<Gaussian>()
    {
        // Estimate a suitable guess for the Gaussian kernel's parameters.
        // This estimate can serve as a starting point for a grid search.
        UseKernelEstimation = true
    }
};

// The following line is only needed to ensure reproducible results. Please remove it to enable full parallelization
teacher.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1; // (Remove, comment, or change this line to enable full parallelism)

// Learn a machine
var machine = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);

// Obtain class predictions for each sample
int[] predicted = machine.Decide(inputs);

// Get class scores for each sample
double[] scores = machine.Score(inputs);

// Compute classification error
double error = new ZeroOneLoss(outputs).Loss(predicted);
```

I tryied it on my own, and it works, classifying inputs as belonging to 0, 1, 2, correctly.

But the same doesn't apply to my data. In particular, my `input` is a `DataObject` class instance, where I join a numerical matrix and an integer array (categories; import has been successfully accomplished, I double checked). The problem is that, while in the reported example `predict` contains the integer corresponding to the labels 0, 1, 2, in my case the predicted labels are only 0 and 1, while in the original dataset I have 0, ... , 5 (adapted from the 3, ... , 8 that were in the raw data).

NOTE: how made in the example has been applied to my input, **but in the line**

```
int [] predict = machine.Decide(TestSet.ItemsFeatures);
```

**I used** the vectors of the test set, and in the line

```
double error = new ZeroOneLoss(TestSet.CatsIDs).Loss(predict);
```

the respective labels, being `CatsIDs` the `Int32` array used to label each vector. I used the Linear kernel instead of the Gaussian, thus *reducing* the error to around 0.49.

What in particular I wanted to find out is: may it be a problem of the data? Should I explore some further the properties of the classes here used? Another question I cannot do answer is: SVM is a binary classifyier, but in the previous example it is successfully used for multiclass classification, while I obtain a two categories classification (with a non negligible error). Is there some conceptual error in my workflow? And about the code: I use the training set on the `Learn` method, then for `Decide()` test set is instead used, which I think is reasonable, but I am not 100% sure about the usage of the test set in the last line, for the error. I think that like how reported is corrected, so comparing the labels of the test set and the mapping of the prediction.

I would like to thank in advance anybody, any help is enormoulsy appreciated.

PS. I am quite new to both C# and Machine Learning, forgive my eventual misunderstoods or shallow comprehensions. Furthermore, how exposed is exclusively needed for an academic exercise. No Accord.NET neither Data linked are used improperly.

I attach a snipped of my code (DataObject and DataAquisition are working pretty good)
**NOTE:** `SetsData[0]` = Test Set; `SetsData[1]` = Training Set.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathFolderSourceData = @"C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\MLProj2018\IO\Source";
            string pathFolderDropData = @"C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\MLProj2018\IO\Drop";

            // data import and new labels
            DataSetImport DSIn = new DataSetImport(pathFolderSourceData);
            DataObject DataMatrix = DSIn.FeaturesImport();

            // DataSet partitioning: - TestSet (10% out of the DS); - TrainingSet (remaining 90%)
            DataSetPartition DSPrt = new DataSetPartition(DataMatrix);
            DataObject[] SetsData = DSPrt.TestSetExtraction(DataMatrix);

            // write sets train and test on file to check the correctness of the 
            // previous classes
            StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(pathFolderDropData + @"\SplittedDataSet.dat");
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < SetsData[k].GetDimensionRows(); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < SetsData[k].ItemsFeats[i].Length; j++)
                    {
                        write.Write("{0}\t", SetsData[k].ItemsFeats[i][j]);
                    } write.Write("{0}\n", SetsData[k].CatIDs[i]);
                }
                write.Write("\n\n\n");
            }
            write.Close();

            // data aquired, now I train the algorithm

            var teacher = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<Linear>()
            {
                Learner = (p) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<Linear>()
                {
                    // UseKernelEstimation = true,
                    UseComplexityHeuristic = true
                }
            };

            // this is for learning parameters w and b, thus eventually 
            // draw the margin
            var machine = teacher.Learn(SetsData[1].ItemsFeats, SetsData[1].CatIDs);

            // parameters have been learned, here I put TestSet SetsData[0] 
            // as entries to be predicted, so the classification of the 
            // test set vectors can be performed
            int[] predicted = machine.Decide(SetsData[0].ItemsFeats);

            double error = new ZeroOneLoss(SetsData[0].CatIDs).Loss(predicted);

            for (int i = 0; i < predicted.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(predicted[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(error);

            // end program
            Console.WriteLine("E N D _ P R O G R A M");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```